# How can I ask Siri to turn OFF Do Not Disturb mode?

Tags: ios, siri

As from iOS 6, I can ask Siri something like "Don't Disturb Me", and it replies confirming that Do Not Disturb is activated.

However, I have not been able to deactivate Do Not Disturb mode by voice.

What verbiage should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, You could ask Siri that all you want, but she wasn’t programmed to toggle that switch for you.

[image]

Until now on iOS 12 - we now have sweet satisfaction in voice mastery over this toggle.